# API server call to OpenAI "An error occurred during the API call: Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to use the OpenAI chat api in my code, but keep getting a 404 error. This is my server.js (With my api key removed which is definitely valid, I've triple checked).

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'removed',
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

app.post('/api/chat', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { input } = req.body;

    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: input }],
    });

    const aiMessage = response.data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
    res.json({ aiMessage });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in API call:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during the API call' });
  }
});
```

If I call the endpoint with Postman, I get this extremely long error in my server log.

```
[1] Error in API call: Error: Request failed with status code 400
[1]     at createError (C:\Users\TheNomadicAspie\Desktop\menu-app\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
[1]     at settle (C:\Users\TheNomadicAspie\Desktop\menu-app\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
[1]     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\TheNomadicAspie\Desktop\menu-app\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
[1]     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
[1]     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
[1]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {[1]   config: {
[1]     transitional: {
[1]       silentJSONParsing: true,
[1]       forcedJSONParsing: true,
[1]       clarifyTimeoutError: false
[1]     },
[1]     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
[1]     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
[1]     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
[1]     timeout: 0,
[1]     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
[1]     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
[1]     maxContentLength: -1,
[1]     maxBodyLength: -1,
[1]     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
[1]     headers: {
[1]       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
[1]       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
[1]       'User-Agent': 'OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1',
[1]       Authorization: 'Bearer removed',  
[1]       'Content-Length': 54
[1]     },
[1]     method: 'post',
[1]     data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user"}]}',
[1]     url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
[1]   },
[1]   request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
[1]     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
[1]       abort: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       connect: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       error: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       socket: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
[1]     },
[1]     _eventsCount: 7,
[1]     _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]     outputData: [],
[1]     outputSize: 0,
[1]     writable: true,
[1]     destroyed: false,
[1]     _last: true,
[1]     chunkedEncoding: false,
[1]     shouldKeepAlive: false,
[1]     maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
[1]     _defaultKeepAlive: true,
[1]     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
[1]     sendDate: false,
[1]     _removedConnection: false,
[1]     _removedContLen: false,
[1]     _removedTE: false,
[1]     strictContentLength: false,
[1]     _contentLength: 54,
[1]     _hasBody: true,
[1]     _trailer: '',
[1]     finished: true,
[1]     _headerSent: true,
[1]     _closed: false,
[1]     socket: TLSSocket {
[1]       _tlsOptions: [Object],
[1]       _secureEstablished: true,
[1]       _securePending: false,
[1]       _newSessionPending: false,
[1]       _controlReleased: true,
[1]       secureConnecting: false,
[1]       _SNICallback: null,
[1]       servername: 'api.openai.com',
[1]       alpnProtocol: false,
[1]       authorized: true,
[1]       authorizationError: null,
[1]       encrypted: true,
[1]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       _eventsCount: 10,
[1]       connecting: false,
[1]       _hadError: false,
[1]       _parent: null,
[1]       _host: 'api.openai.com',
[1]       _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
[1]       _readableState: [ReadableState],
[1]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]       _writableState: [WritableState],
[1]       allowHalfOpen: false,
[1]       _sockname: null,
[1]       _pendingData: null,
[1]       _pendingEncoding: '',
[1]       server: undefined,
[1]       _server: null,
[1]       ssl: [TLSWrap],
[1]       _requestCert: true,
[1]       _rejectUnauthorized: true,
[1]       parser: null,
[1]       _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
[1]       [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
[1]       [Symbol(verified)]: true,
[1]       [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 25,
[1]       [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
[1]       [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
[1]       [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[1]       [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
[1]       [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
[1]       [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
[1]       [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
[1]       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
[1]       [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
[1]     },
[1]     _header: 'POST /v1/chat/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
[1]       'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
[1]       'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
[1]       'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1\r\n' +
[1]       'Authorization: Bearer removed\r\n' +
[1]       'Content-Length: 54\r\n' +
[1]       'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
[1]       'Connection: close\r\n' +
[1]       '\r\n',
[1]     _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
[1]     _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
[1]     agent: Agent {
[1]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       _eventsCount: 2,
[1]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]       defaultPort: 443,
[1]       protocol: 'https:',
[1]       options: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
[1]       sockets: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
[1]       keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
[1]       keepAlive: false,
[1]       maxSockets: Infinity,
[1]       maxFreeSockets: 256,
[1]       scheduling: 'lifo',
[1]       maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
[1]       totalSocketCount: 1,
[1]       maxCachedSessions: 100,
[1]       _sessionCache: [Object],
[1]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
[1]     },
[1]     socketPath: undefined,
[1]     method: 'POST',
[1]     maxHeaderSize: undefined,
[1]     insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
[1]     joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
[1]     path: '/v1/chat/completions',
[1]     _ended: true,
[1]     res: IncomingMessage {
[1]       _readableState: [ReadableState],
[1]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       _eventsCount: 4,
[1]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]       socket: [TLSSocket],
[1]       httpVersionMajor: 1,
[1]       httpVersionMinor: 1,
[1]       httpVersion: '1.1',
[1]       complete: true,
[1]       rawHeaders: [Array],
[1]       rawTrailers: [],
[1]       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
[1]       aborted: false,
[1]       upgrade: false,
[1]       url: '',
[1]       method: null,
[1]       statusCode: 400,
[1]       statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
[1]       client: [TLSSocket],
[1]       _consuming: false,
[1]       _dumped: false,
[1]       req: [Circular *1],
[1]       responseUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
[1]       redirects: [],
[1]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[1]       [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
[1]       [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 40,
[1]       [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
[1]     },
[1]     aborted: false,
[1]     timeoutCb: null,
[1]     upgradeOrConnect: false,
[1]     parser: null,
[1]     maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]     reusedSocket: false,
[1]     host: 'api.openai.com',
[1]     protocol: 'https:',
[1]     _redirectable: Writable {
[1]       _writableState: [WritableState],
[1]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       _eventsCount: 3,
[1]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]       _options: [Object],
[1]       _ended: true,
[1]       _ending: true,
[1]       _redirectCount: 0,
[1]       _redirects: [],
[1]       _requestBodyLength: 54,
[1]       _requestBodyBuffers: [],
[1]       _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
[1]       _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
[1]       _currentUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
[1]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
[1]     },
[1]     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[1]     [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
[1]     [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
[1]     [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
[1]     [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
[1]     [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
[1]       accept: [Array],
[1]       'content-type': [Array],
[1]       'user-agent': [Array],
[1]       authorization: [Array],
[1]       'content-length': [Array],
[1]       host: [Array]
[1]     },
[1]     [Symbol(errored)]: null,
[1]     [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
[1]   },
[1]   response: {
[1]     status: 400,
[1]     statusText: 'Bad Request',
[1]     headers: {
[1]       date: 'Tue, 16 May 2023 02:22:58 GMT',
[1]       'content-type': 'application/json',
[1]       'content-length': '160',
[1]       connection: 'close',
[1]       'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
[1]       'openai-organization': 'user-tblz934t92ja8twwukcaheq7',
[1]       'openai-processing-ms': '208',
[1]       'openai-version': '2020-10-01',
[1]       'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
[1]       'x-ratelimit-limit-requests': '3500',
[1]       'x-ratelimit-limit-tokens': '90000',
[1]       'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests': '3499',
[1]       'x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens': '89983',
[1]       'x-ratelimit-reset-requests': '17ms',
[1]       'x-ratelimit-reset-tokens': '11ms',
[1]       'x-request-id': '9291039cf2af6385af913b1be36d2803',
[1]       'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
[1]       server: 'cloudflare',
[1]       'cf-ray': '7c8027ec5fca09f1-LAS',
[1]       'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'
[1]     },
[1]     config: {
[1]       transitional: [Object],
[1]       adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
[1]       transformRequest: [Array],
[1]       transformResponse: [Array],
[1]       timeout: 0,
[1]       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
[1]       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
[1]       maxContentLength: -1,
[1]       maxBodyLength: -1,
[1]       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
[1]       headers: [Object],
[1]       method: 'post',
[1]       data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user"}]}',
[1]       url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
[1]     },
[1]     request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
[1]       _events: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       _eventsCount: 7,
[1]       _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]       outputData: [],
[1]       outputSize: 0,
[1]       writable: true,
[1]       destroyed: false,
[1]       _last: true,
[1]       chunkedEncoding: false,
[1]       shouldKeepAlive: false,
[1]       maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
[1]       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
[1]       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
[1]       sendDate: false,
[1]       _removedConnection: false,
[1]       _removedContLen: false,
[1]       _removedTE: false,
[1]       strictContentLength: false,
[1]       _contentLength: 54,
[1]       _hasBody: true,
[1]       _trailer: '',
[1]       finished: true,
[1]       _headerSent: true,
[1]       _closed: false,
[1]       socket: [TLSSocket],
[1]       _header: 'POST /v1/chat/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
[1]         'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
[1]         'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
[1]         'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1\r\n' +
[1]         'Authorization: Bearer removed\r\n' +
[1]         'Content-Length: 54\r\n' +
[1]         'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
[1]         'Connection: close\r\n' +
[1]         '\r\n',
[1]       _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
[1]       _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
[1]       agent: [Agent],
[1]       socketPath: undefined,
[1]       method: 'POST',
[1]       maxHeaderSize: undefined,
[1]       insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
[1]       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
[1]       path: '/v1/chat/completions',
[1]       _ended: true,
[1]       res: [IncomingMessage],
[1]       aborted: false,
[1]       timeoutCb: null,
[1]       upgradeOrConnect: false,
[1]       parser: null,
[1]       maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]       reusedSocket: false,
[1]       host: 'api.openai.com',
[1]       protocol: 'https:',
[1]       _redirectable: [Writable],
[1]       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
[1]       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
[1]       [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
[1]       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
[1]       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
[1]       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
[1]       [Symbol(errored)]: null,
[1]       [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
[1]     },
[1]     data: { error: [Object] }
[1]   },
[1]   isAxiosError: true,
[1]   toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
[1] }
```

I've looked at answers from people with similar problems, and tried various models and methods of calling open including calling the url directly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: check the api key is/not expired. generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error if I did not pass the request body when calling the post request.

You see there is

```
data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user"}]}',
```

in your error log.

The correct example of error log should look like:

```
data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user","content":"Hello world"}]}',
```

if you do pass the json body.

Try to include the json body in your request will resolve the error.

For instance, try in Postman putting:

```
{
 "input": "Helo World"
}
```

[image: Json body]